# new constructors in javascript object methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, new-operator

Hey i'm just looking for a javascript explanation to explain why 'constructor called' is only called once as opposed to 5 times?

```
const Dog = function(name, age){
  this.name = name; 
  this.age = age; 
  console.log('constructor called'); 
}
```

```
const obj = { 
  dog: new Dog('roofus', 20)
}
```

```
const main = ()=>{
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    console.log(obj.dog)
  }
}
```

```
main();
'constructor called'
Dog { name: 'roofus', age: 20 }
Dog { name: 'roofus', age: 20 }
Dog { name: 'roofus', age: 20 }
Dog { name: 'roofus', age: 20 }
Dog { name: 'roofus', age: 20 }
```

Comment: why do you think `Dog` is called 5 times? The instance that you've created is logged 5 times, but `new Dog()` is only called once, when you define `obj`.

Comment: is it because the new keyword is immediately executing the constructor function inside obj?

Comment: @Rez88 That is correct :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a property on your object named `dog`, the expression `new Dog(...)` is evaluated immediately. This is why you only see one log as the constructor is only called once.

This is a version that would call the constructor 5 times:

```
const obj = {
  // Notice the use of a function here. 
  dog: () => new Dog('roofus', 20)
}
```

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    // Call the function here.
    console.log(obj.dog())
}
```